# Custom domain emails with Square?

Tags: email, domain, website

A friend of mine wants an eCommerce website and asked me to set on up using square ([Squareup](http://square.com/online-store) **not** squarespace). They would also like to have a custom email, like hello@example.com. Is this possible to achieve using square? I don't think so, but I do hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square does not offer a domain registrar service, so you cannot obtain a new .com or .net address through their tools. However, you can add a Square online store to an existing custom domain.

This [Square help article](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5111) walks through the steps of configuring your DNS to point to a Square online store. After this is complete, you can set up custom email addresses through your domain registrar account.